# Is there any way to modify the default protocol schemes recognized by the Rich Edit control when using EM_AUTOURLDETECT?

Tags: c++, winapi, url, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to determine if there is any way to modify the default set of protocol schemes that the Rich Edit Control when using EM_AUTOURLDETECT as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787991(v=vs.85).aspx

In other words, when the EM_AUTOURLDETECT message is sent to the controland LPARAM is NULL, the following set of protocol schemes are recognized and displayed as a hyperlink:

- callto
- file
- ftp
- gopher
- http
- https
- mailto
- news
- notes
- nntp
- onenote
- outlook
- prospero
- tel
- telnet
- wais
- webcal

My question is if it is possible to alter (add to) this list?

Is it hard coded or might it be stored in the registry somewhere?

I realize that it is possible to specify the list explicitly via LPARAM, but I am looking for a way to accomplish this without modifying the existing code (which is passing NULL for LPARAM).

More specifically, I'm trying to find a way to get TortoiseSVN's log view dialog to recognize a URL protocol which isn't on this list, without modifying the code.  Here's a link to the related code:

http://code.google.com/searchframe#XJa9F1p-bAg/trunk/src/TortoiseProc/LogDialog/LogDlg.cpp&q=EM_AUTOURLDETECT%20package:http://tortoisesvn%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=1&sq=

This may be more of a SuperUser question, but since it relates to the way EM_AUTOURLDETECT works, I'm hoping someone here might know the answer.

Does anyone know if the source for the Rich Edit control is available anywhere?

Comment: If it's taken from all protocols registered, [`this`](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-does-one-add-a-new-protocol-and-the-handling/c8e5389c-5c28-4ed4-80fa-9ca743c17009) might be helpful for you. [`Here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx#app_reg) is the MSDN reference.